# Riley Riddle taken two steps further

Tags: riddle

- My prefix is in affirmation
- My suffix in its full form is filled with folklore
- My infix was discovered
- My circumfix keeps you up to date
- My transfix might be bought when you're out with friends
- My whole is far below the surface

---

As seemingly standard in these riddles, we'll not take a strict linguistic definition of the affixes. With example of "hello" and "green", I expect the following:

Circumfix: **{hel}**blabla**{lo}**

Transfix: bl**{gr}**ab**{een}**la

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My prefix is in affirmation

> pro - affirming a postition

My suffix in its full form is filled with folklore

> ness - Loch Ness is famous for tales of its monster

My infix was discovered

> found is discovered

My circumfix keeps you up to date

> press - the news media for current affairs

My transfix might be bought when you're out with friends

> round - a round of pints in a bar

My whole is far below the surface

> profoundness - descending far below the surface, intellectually deep

Comment: Wow that was very impressive